# alias not getting triggered when defined within bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am writing a script that fetches inventory for Kubernetes deployments. This script will fetch multiple environments, So I am aliasing those env, so for every env it will run the kube-config command and then fetch the data. But alias command is not getting triggered within the script.
Thanks in advance.

Error:

```
pepprodeuold
pepprodeuold: command not found
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
PROFILE="env-prod"
REGIONS=("eu-central-1" "us-east-1")
CLUSTERS_CONTEXT=("pepprodeu" "pepprodus" "pepprodeuold")

shopt -s expand_aliases

# Define Aliases for Cluster
alias pepprodeuold="kubectl config use-context arn"
alias pepprodeu="kubectl config use-context arn1"
alias pepprodus="kubectl config use-context arn2"


function clean_old_files ()
 {
    echo "##################################### Cleaning old Files ###############################################"
    echo "Clean up Previous Reports"
    rm -rf eks_deployment_report.txt eks_node_report.txt
    get_eks_report
}

function get_deployment_count()
 {
    echo "##################################### Generating EKS DEPLOYMENT Report #####################################"
    echo "No of Deployments in ${cluster}"  >> eks_deployment_report.txt
    kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.namespace}{"\t"}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.spec.replicas}{"\n"}{end}' | awk '$3 > 0 {count[$1]++} END {for (namespace in count) {print namespace, count[namespace]}}' | column -t | tee eks_deployment_report.txt
    echo "No of Nodes in ${cluster}" >> eks_node_report.txt
    kubectl get nodes --no-headers | wc -l | tee eks_node_report.txt
}

function get_eks_report() {
    for cluster in "${CLUSTERS_CONTEXT[@]}"; do
            echo "######################################## Get EKS Details in ${cluster} Cluster ########################################"
            echo "${cluster}"
            ${cluster}
            get_deployment_count
        done
}

clean_old_files
```

Comment: I don't see in your script, where you invoke the alias (`pepprodeuold`).

Comment: Aliases are disabled in scripts (at least by default). As usual, the best solution is to use functions instead of aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases):

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt` (see The [Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)).
>
> [...]
>
> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.